# React-notification-component keeps showing TypeError: this.add is not a function

Tags: reactjs

I followed the steps on the NPM page for [`react-notifications-component`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notifications-component) but I keep getting "TypeError: this.add is not a function".

Steps:

1. Install using `npm install react-notifications-component`.
2. Install animate.css using `npm install animate.css`.
3. Import react-notifications-component and `store`.

```
import ReactNotification, { store } from "react-notifications-component";
import "react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css";
import "animate.css/animate.min.css";
```

4. Include `<ReactNotification />` in my App.js render.

```
function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <ReactNotification />
    </div>
  );
}
```

5. Then call `store.addNotification()` before returning JSX, exactly as written on the NPM page.

```
store.addNotification({
  title: "Wonderful!",
  message: "teodosii@react-notifications-component",
  type: "success",
  insert: "top",
  container: "top-right",
  animationIn: ["animate__animated", "animate__fadeIn"],
  animationOut: ["animate__animated", "animate__fadeOut"],
  dismiss: {
    duration: 5000,
    onScreen: true
  }
});
```

However, I just keep getting a `TypeError: this.add is not a function`

```
TypeError: this.add is not a function
Store.addNotification
src/store/index.ts:49
  46 |      this.types,
  47 |      this.defaultNotificationWidth
  48 |    );
> 49 |    return this.add(parsedNotification);
     | ^  50 |  }
  51 | 
  52 |  public getCounter = () => this.counter;
View compiled
```

This was all done in a brand new repo after running `npx create-react-app`. Any idea what I might have done wrong?

Comment: @lawrence-witt thanks, the src/store/index.ts comes from the `react-notification-component` library, the full file is available from its repo here: https://github.com/teodosii/react-notifications-component/blob/master/src/store/index.ts

Comment: I am having the same issue. Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: @Marco Unfortunately no, but I switched to [react-notifications](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notifications) which is basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

Probably not relevant for you since you have switched to another package but for anyone who is stuck:
First use imports in your `app.js` and make sure you are rendering it along any component from which you are calling it

```
import React from 'react'
import './App.css';
import TestDashboard from './components/Dashboard';
import ReactNotification from 'react-notifications-component'
import 'react-notifications-component/dist/theme.css'

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
        <ReactNotification />
        <Dashboard />
    </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

If you are using next, check you have put it as shown above in the `_app.js`

Then you call notifications from Dashboard or any child component so it will show properly. Also make sure you have run `npm run build:library:dev` before running it

Comment: mine npm run build:library:dev is not working please any solution

Comment: @Arinzehills what is the error you are getting? Since this is related to the NPM package perhaps you can reach out to the author - https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-notifications-component

Comment: it says npm ERR! Missing script: "build:library:dev"