# react-notifications-component custom content example

Tags: reactjs, react-notifications-component

I am using react-notifications-component and I see that I can have a custom component shown by setting .content of the iNotification object passed to Store.addNotification().  I would like to add a control to the existing component that comes with this library (I want to add a button to copy the message to the clipboard).  If I could extend the existing component, this could be relatively easy, but I don't see how to do this.  I don't want to "reinvent the wheel" since the 'native' component works and looks great.

Does anyone have examples of this type of functionality?
Thanks.

Comment: I wanted to have a look at it, but I cant even run the package, does it work for you? I get this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67755141/react-notification-component-keeps-showing-typeerror-this-add-is-not-a-function

Answer (score 0):

I dont think there is way to do it, unless you ask the author.. But honestly its fairly easy to implement own component that looks just like the original one, so I dont think it would even make sense to have this functionality, but you can ask..
Anyway I played around and made custom component which copies text ( but from `input` not from a `div` therefore the style broke a bit, but if you have a `div` it again looks just the same..

[working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/zen-keller-tj7u76?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: I was trying to utilize a lot of the nice extra features (i.e. progress bar counting down, close button, close on click, etc.) without having to rewrite it but, as you state, it's not overly complex.  It's actually a cleaner solution writing my own rather than trying to manipulate the out-of-the-box functionality.  Thank you!